# Understanding jQuery $.extend() correct usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have a [jQuery image gallery plugin](https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus/blob/master/jquery.collagePlus.js#L26) and a recent pull request made me question whether I am using `extend()` correctly.

I currently use the format:

```
$.fn.collagePlus = function( options ) {

    // Defaults
    var settings = $.extend( {
        "someDefault" : true
        ...
    }, options);
```

but [reading the documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/), it seems I should be doing:

```
var settings = $.extend( {}, $.fn.collagePlus.defaults, options );
```

although I have some defaults that are dynamic so probably I should do:

```
var defaults = { "someDefault" : true };
var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
```

What approach should I be using?

Comment: Well, a public `$.fn.collagePlus.defaults` object would allow the user to change the defaults directly. It's a design question, and has nothing to do with "correct usage" of `$.extend`

Answer (score 2):

The extend method can be described as below:

```
$.extend(target, more1, more2, moreN);
```

where `target` will be the object that is extented with all of the properties from `more1...N` in that order:

```
var target = {};
var more1 = {a: 1, b: 2};
var more2 = {b: -2, c: -3};

$.extend(target, more1, more2);

console.log(target); // {a: 1, b: -2, c: -3}
```

As you can see the target object will be recieve the properties from first more1 and then more2.

As for your situation, you can use all three, but I will suggest you to use the second approach as that it gives you the possibility to overwrite defaults because they are accessible from the global scope using: (`$.fn.plugin.defaults`).

### $.fn.plugin.defaults

Then a user of your plugin can set defaults for the plugin in that content (s)he is using it:

```
$.fn.plugin.defaults.something = false;
```

And not having the initialize the plugin multiply times with that information:

```
// Top of file, config file or so:
$.fn.plugin.defaults.something = false;

// Somewhere else
$(a).plugin();
$(b).plugin();

// If this pattern is not used you will have to do:
$(a).plugin({something: false});
$(b).plugin({something: false});
```

---

### $.extend(true, target, more);

A side node is that if `true` is passed as the first argument to `$.extend` the jQuery will make a deep clone rater than a shallow clone:

```
var target = { a: { a: 1 } };
var more = { a: { b: 2 } };

$.extend(target, more); 
console.log(target) { a: { b: 2 } }


var target = { a: { a: 1 } };
var more = { a: { b: 2 } };
//         V--- Note true here
$.extend(true, target, more); 
console.log(target) { a: { a: 1, b: 2 } }
```

---

### Static vs Dynamic Defaults:

```
$.fn.plugin = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
         var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.plugin.defaults, {
             images: $(this).children()
         }, arguments[0]);
    });
};

$.fn.plugin.defaults = { something: true, text: "Default Text" };
```

Comment: with ```$.fn.plugin.defaults``` how could I support dynamic defaults like here https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus/blob/master/jquery.collagePlus.js#L30 ?

Comment: I would put all static defaults in $.fn.plugin.defaults and then but dynamicDefaults in a small object as the second arguments see above.

Comment: Also you could use a selector to fetch the images and then be able to handle delayed appended elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your first call is ok, because options would be merged into the first object (defaults) which is created and used only there. The second syntax is only needed if your defaults object is declared in another place and shared between multiple calls, because of the danger that the default object is changed by the merge.